# vue-router default child route for tabs

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to have a homepage with tabs containing 2 lists, with 1 open by default.

I have the following route config, I've changed the names to simplify

```
let routes = [{
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: require('./views/Home.vue'),
    children: [{
        path: 'list1',
        name: 'home.list1',
        component: require('./views/List1.vue')
    }, {
        path: 'list2',
        name: 'home.list2',
        component: require('./views/List2.vue')
    }]
}
```

Inside `./views/Home.vue` I have a `<router-view></router-view>` below 2 `<router-link>`s for each tab (child route).

When I visit the app route `http://domain/` I would like to activate the `list1` tab. The only way I can currently do this is if I visit `http://domain/list1`.

I have tried

```
children: [{
    path: '',
    name: 'home.list1'
```

and this initially works well, however if I visit `http://domain/list2` both my tab links (router-links) have the active state.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wtpuevc6/33/) which I can't get to run but helps for context

Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html see example on very bottom of the page.

Comment: @Eggy but when you define a second child route, when it's active both child `<router-link>` will be active

Comment: It's hard to tell without example. But you can try `exact` prop on router link https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html

Comment: Example added to OP

Comment: @Eggy exact worked thank you! Want to post it as an answer so I can mark as answered?

Answer (score 18):

Add one more child route with redirect (should be first)

```
  children: [{
    path: '',
    redirect: 'list1', // default child path
  },
  ...
  ]
```

Answer (score 11):

For making a component(tab) appear default at visiting the parent route, you need to add a path as '' (empty string)

The following is a n example from the Vue Router docs

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/user/:id', component: User,
      children: [
        // UserHome will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
        // when /user/:id is matched
        { path: '', component: UserHome },

        // ...other sub routes
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

Don't use a '/', it will be considered as the root route.

Answer (score 8):

You need to put the redirect on the parent, and it works on the first load.
Otherwise, it only works when I reload the page.

- put redirect: 'home.list1' on the parent
- put your child as path: ''

hope it works.

```
let routes = [{
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        redirect: {name: 'home.list1'}, // Redirect to named route
        // redirect '/list2' // Or redirect to path
        component: require('./views/Home.vue'),
        children: [{
            path: '',
            name: 'home.list1',
            component: require('./views/List1.vue')
        }, {
            path: 'list2',
            name: 'home.list2',
            component: require('./views/List2.vue')
        }]
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what works.

You have to use `redirect: {name: 'home.list1'}` (for the named route) property on your parent route `'home'`.

Make sure you use the correct redirect property format either for named route (as above) or for path: `redirect: '/list1'`.

Here is the correct routes config which is only 1 line (the `redirect` one) different vs your config:

```js
const routes = [{
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        redirect: 'home.list1',
        component: require('./views/Home.vue'),
        children: [{
            path: 'list1',
            name: 'home.list1',
            component: require('./views/List1.vue')
        }, {
            path: 'list2',
            name: 'home.list2',
            component: require('./views/List2.vue')
        }]
    }
```

Then every visit to `/` (your `'home'` route) would be redirected to `/list1`.

Moreover, the `router-link-active` and `router-link-exact-active` will be correctly assigned on child link (both of them) and on parent link (only `router-link-active`).

This will also work for deeper nested non-child and child routes.

For more redirect & aliasig options see the [official docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do works if your home route isn't "/"

```
routes: [
    { path: '/home', 
        name: 'home',
        component: require('./views/home.vue')
        children: [
            { path: '/', name: 'list1', component: list1 },
            { path: 'list2', name: 'list2', component: list2},
        ],
    }
]
```

This will load the home component and the list1 component inside of your initial .  Then  you can user router link to nav to list2:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'list2', params: { ...}}">
```

Or, maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: I can't get the fiddle to run but here it is for context: http://jsfiddle.net/wtpuevc6/33/

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way I've found to do it, preserving the route parameters:

```
{
  path: "/users/:id(\\d+)",
  component: Users,
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      redirect: { name: "ChildOne" },
    },
    {
      path: "child-one",
      name: "ChildOne",
      component: ChildOne,
    },
    {
      path: "child-two",
      component: ChildTwo,
    },
    {
      path: "child-three",
      component: ChildThree,
    },
  ],
},
```

For example, when navigating to /users/1, the route is redirected to /users/1/child-one. I found that when I do it with a path, the id is not treated as a route param and is instead treated as text (so would try to redirect to /users/:id/child-one instead)